# Rewrite not working with xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

This simple rewrite is not working. I have already tested this on my server that runs linux and it works.
http://www.lokislayer.com/mvc/bob   -- page displays bob like it should --

localhost does not work with xampp installed:

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]enter code here
```

Simple index.php File

```
<?php
   $url = $_GET['url'];
   echo $url;
 ?>
```

Error Message from php : 
Notice: Undefined index: url in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\mvc\source\index.php on line 3

The code does not work unless I remove the 2nd RewriteCond. I do have mod rewrite working because on the same xampp installation I am running MagentoCE 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to place above code in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/mvc/source/.htaccess` and have your code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mvc/source/

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Important change is the use of [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

Comment: Does not still work?  My project is in DOCUMENT_ROOT/mvc/source. I even copied your exact wording and still getting that it can not find $url in the index even though it works on my a linux apache environment.

Comment: Ok I made an edit. Above code should be in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/mvc/source/.htaccess`. Try it out.

Comment: still does not work.

It works if I remove RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f line because I have tried removing the line. It works but does not work like it does on a linux server.

Comment: Ok for which URL it doesn't work as you expected? Try giving as much details as possible so that I can help you better. Do you have any other .htaccess anywhere in your system OR any other rules in this .htaccess? I made an edit also, try edited code.